# Php Laravel bind php variable with html select

Tags: php, data-binding, drop-down-menu, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am very new to php laravel.
I need to populate a dropdown in php blade with certain list I send to the view and I need to bind the selected value with a certain php variable.

My code:

```
<div class="dropdown" id="managerDropdown">
    {{ Form::select($row->manager_id,Manager::getSelectOptions(),$row->manager_id) }}
</div>
```

I'm not understanding how do I bind my "$row->manager_id" with this drop down, so that when I submit, "$row->manager->id" will have selected records id(value).

Comment: Is your `Manager::getAll()` have values?

Comment: @aldrin27, I just changed my code. It populates the drop down properly just does not reflect in the variable.

Comment: `Manager::getSelectOptions()` should be an associative array which contains (at some point) the `$row->manager_id` as the key. Can you confirm that this is the case?

Comment: Can you also tell me how do I print an object/dictionary my terminal? or debug a laravel controller?

Comment: @apokryfos , yes it is selecting the correct item from the list when loaded.

Comment: @AarohiKulkarni sorry, I misunderstood your question. Short answer is, HTTP is stateless and you can't really reuse your `$row` variable after you submit the form. A way around this is to store `$row` in the session and then get the value from the form via `\Input::get(<id from session>)`.

Comment: @apokryfos, actually I get the $row dictionary from my controller(server). And the \Input::get(<id from session>) works for all the rest attributes which are text fields like name, username.

Comment: Showing the complete resulting form may help.

Comment: Oh I only should have written manager_id instead of $row->manager_id as the id of my select tag. Working now. :)